# Waiting for DOM to load in JSNI GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, dom, jsni

I'm currently having a problem where the javascript seems to be executing before the DOM is completely loaded. Why do i say this? Take the following code:

```
var $r = $wnd.Raphael("container", 640, 480);

// Creates pie chart at with center at 320, 200,
// radius 100 and data: [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2]
$r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [ 55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2 ]);
```

returns a Javascript exception: 'f is null'. Which seems to indicate that the container name is not recognized.

If specify absolute coordinates the piechart is rendered fine. If i use the previous code in the Chrome console (after all is loaded) it effectively, loads the piechart into the container  tag.

I've tried wrapping the block of code in a JQuery call:

```
$wnd.jQuery(function($) {
            // Creates canvas 640 × 480 at 10, 50
            var $r = $wnd.Raphael("container", 640, 480);
            // Creates pie chart at with center at 320, 200,
            // radius 100 and data: [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2]
            $r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [ 55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2 ]);
    });
```

... And no dice.

Any ideias of what i could try?

EDIT:

Here's how/where i'm calling the JSNI method. The following is the relevant View code.

```
public class WidgetSamplerView extends AbstractPanelView implements
                WidgetSamplerPresenter.Display { 

private FlexTable mainPanel;

public WidgetSamplerView() {
        super();

            mainPanel = new FlexTable();

            HTML container = new HTML();
        container.getElement().setAttribute("style",
                "width:700px;height:700px");
        container.getElement().setId("container");

        mainPanel.setWidget(0, 1, container);

        MyRaphaelWrapper.pieChart(); // JSNI Call

        setWidget(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just guessing: Perhaps Raphael tries to look at the wrong DOM? I'd try $wnd.Raphael($doc.getElementById("container"), 640, 480);

Comment: we need to see some more context code, such as the JSNI call. are you calling the JSNI wrapping method on the appropriate phase (`onLoad`, `onAttach`, `onRender` etc.)?

Comment: @StefanHaustein No dice, It returned 'f is null'. Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: @EliranMalka I'm just calling it statically within a Presenter after adding a bunch of other widgets to the main container panel of the application.

Comment: please enclose the presenter code as well, this will give us (and you) more clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make sure you call the JSNI method only when `onLoad()` is activated, to verify the widget has loaded.

See [another answer of mine on best practices for creating and initializing widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651482/547020), for a quick reference.

The basic idea is to override `onLoad()` on the widget and call any loading functionality there:

```java
public class MainPanel extends FlexTable {

    private Element container;

    public MainPanel() {

        container = DOM.createDiv();
        container.setId("container");

        // this is required by the Widget API to define the underlying element
        setElement(container);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();

            MyRaphaelWrapper.pieChart(); // JSNI Call
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was relying on the JQuery to check for DOM completion. I got to this exact solution just a few minutes before you posted, but anyway, this is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Raphael is doing the following internally:

```
document.getElementById("container");
```

If you compile your GWT app with standard settings the code is loaded in an iframe. This is why you have to use $wnd instead of window and $doc instead of document. They point to the main window.

How did you include the other javascript library? Because Raphael could be looking inside the wrong DOM (the dom of the iframe). Can you pass the element directly to rapahel with something like this?

```
var c = $doc.getElementById("container");
$wnd.Raphael(c, ..);
```

Comment: 'f is null'. Thanks for the comment though :)